# Dependency tree with "seem"

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, dependency-grammar

Could someone please tell me what's the dep. tree of "John seemed to fall asleep"? The problem is I don't know if "John" depends on "seem" or "fall".

Comment: _Fall_. It's raised to subject position; _seem_ takes a sentential complement with either A-Raising or Extraposition obligatory. Of course, that's not a proper dependency description.

Comment: @johnlawlerinexile Thanks. So the fact that "John" agrees with "seem" (as in "John seems...") is irrelevant for dependencies, right?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "dependencies". There are a lot of ways to approach it. I was just saying how I'd describe it, which is not in a dependency tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In surface syntax it's "John - seemed". In deep syntax it depends on the theory. "John" would depend on "fall" but sometimes there are two heads and one would say that the subject of "seem" is athematic, i.e., it has no thematic role. XDG does it this way, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Many modern DGs would give the sentence the following structure in surface syntax:

[image]

While *seem* is indeed a raising verb, that does not change the fact that the subject is generally positioned as an immediate dependent of the finite verb in many modern DGs. The position of *John* immediately in front of the *seemed* and the fact that *John* agrees with *seemed* (compare: *They seems...) are strong indicators that *John* is an immediate dependent of *seemed*.

If one chooses a DG approach that acknowledges both deep and surface syntax, then one could view *John* as a dependent of *fall* below the surface (i.e. in deep syntax).